# Relink after editing intermediate assembly files

Tags: assembly, rust, reverse-engineering, rust-cargo, roundtrip

We can pass a flag to Cargo that is in turn passed to `rustc` to emit intermediate assembly files for the whole contents of a crate:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS="--emit=asm" cargo rustc --release
```

After running this, indeed we can see a whole lot of `.s` files under `target/$TARGET/release`:

```
$ ls target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/*.{s,elf}
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/avr_config-e311e93c086c3db0.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/avr_delay-157ca9fb1a916f1a.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/avr_progmem-9dc1e040eb728712.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/avr_std_stub-c3510b4296c6559e.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/cfg_if-21f3790d6886cc57.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/compiler_builtins-d2b51c47ad38c941.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/core-195cf775332e0617.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/ruduino-15843435a02e3c3a.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/rustc_std_workspace_core-7426025ff9d9438f.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/ufmt-b3d2cb48639acfb8.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/ufmt_write-4e35e82da143e2d5.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/worduino_avr-b35d7970ef451ba9.elf*
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/worduino_avr-b35d7970ef451ba9.s
target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/worduino_engine-1dc7446bd9d04ccf.s
```

**How do I change some of these and then continue with the same assembly and linking process?** So let's say I edit the file
`target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/worduino_engine-1dc7446bd9d04ccf.s`, how do I then ask Cargo to create a new version of `worduino_avr-b35d7970ef451ba9.elf` with otherwise the same link-time settings as the original invocation of `cargo rustc`?

Comment: Files emitted by `--emit` aren't realy meant to be used other than for inspection, so this is definitely not a usecase of the flag and I doubt it's possible at all.

Comment: @cafce25: OK, so I suppose I'll have to go the scenic route... Is there at least a flag to emit `.s` files that roundtrip with GCC's `avr-as`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my surprise, it turns out, at least for AVR, the assembly code corresponding to the toplevel crate contains everything needed, no linking required. So for e.g. LLVM intermediate files, we can use `llc` for static compilation, and then GCC for trivial linking:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS="--emit=llvm-bc" cargo rustc --release
$ llc-15 -march=avr -mcpu=atmega32u4 -filetype=obj --function-sections target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/worduino_avr-b35d7970ef451ba9.bc -o foo.o
$ avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega32u4 -Os foo.o -o foo.elf
```

This produces a valid ELF file in `foo.elf`, however, it is *not* exactly the same as the one produced by Rust, which is concerning:

```
$ md5sum foo.elf target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/worduino_avr-b35d7970ef451ba9.elf
5ba0a483b6adbc81faaba180e8e5ad1c  foo.elf
198eff7c052172bcff6a9a81306a7bf7  target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/worduino_avr-b35d7970ef451ba9.elf
```

This seems to be because `foo.o` itself doesn't exactly match the intermediate object file `worduino_avr-b35d7970ef451ba9.worduino_avr.124c28c8-cgu.0.rcgu.o` created by Rust; I'm not sure what exactly is going on here.

Functionally, loading the resulting `.elf` file into an AVR simulator, it seems that the result matches the behaviour of the real Rust output, so that's good. Still, it would be better if we could replicate the `.elf` file exactly.

Anyway, moving on the next question is [how to do the same, but from assembly `.s` files instead of `.bc`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75095116/477476). We should be able to replace `llc` with [`llvm-mc`](https://blog.llvm.org/2010/04/intro-to-llvm-mc-project.html) in the above pipeline:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS="--emit=asm" cargo rustc --release
$ llvm-mc-15 --arch=avr --mcpu=atmega32u4 -filetype=obj target/avr-atmega32u4/release/deps/worduino_avr-b35d7970ef451ba9.s -filetype=obj -o bar.o
$ avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega32u4 -Os bar.o -o bar.elf
```

However, here we hit another problem where [`llvm-mc` mis-assembles the file](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/59962).

Comment: It's possible the toolchains are generating random build-IDs as part of the object files.  I'd check `file foo.elf`, and try `diff` on the `readelf -a` and `objdump -drwC` outputs.  If those are the same, that's a good sign.